# PageNotFound: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Having issues with the *DispatcherServlet*, I do believe the problem is in one of the xmls but being new at Spring I'm not being able to identify it.

**HotelController.java** (src\main\java\hotelbooking\controller)

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class HotelController {

    @Autowired
    HotelService hotels;

    @RequestMapping(value="/hotels", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        System.out.println("test");
        model.addAttribute("hotels", hotels.findAllHotels());
        return "allhotels";
    }
}
```

**web.xml** (src\main\webapp\WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
           <init-param>
               <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
               <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
           </init-param>
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml** ()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>hotelbookings</name>
<groupId>CIAI_T1</groupId>
<artifactId>hotelbookings</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
    <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-Time -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>          
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin> <!-- enable java 1.7 -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
        <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** (src\main\webapp\WEB-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"> 

<context:component-scan base-package="hotelbooking.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I have the views in: "\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views" and there I have a file called "allhotels.jsp", I'm trying to open the page with "http://localhost:8080/hotels" (though I'm not sure that's correct).

On front of the file names above is their relative path.

I'm using Spring boot with Maven. If you need me to post anything else please let me know.

Comment: If https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp is right, maybe put it in `\jsp` instead of `\views`?

Comment: @zapl Sorry I forgot to include the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. I tried changing the folder name and the xmp to jsp but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I could see you have used two different names for DispatcherServlet while configuring it in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do the below changes in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"> 

<context:component-scan base-package="hotelbooking.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I feel it's more about web.xml and spring configuration file issue, try using the above modified one and try once.

The Url pattern should be like below

> `http://hostname:port/<webapplication-name>/<controller-path>`
>   `http://localhost:8080/hotelbookings/hotels` (In your case try this assuming 'hotelbookings' as web application name.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still the same. Just to make sure, the web app name is the artifactid/name on the pom.xml?

Comment: Ah right, it is indeed hotelbookings then.

Comment: Indeed I am, specifically the error is: `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hotelbookings/hotels] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'.`

Comment: Still nothing. (I had to add    `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` to the beans)

Comment: Still nothing. Does the `pom.xml` need a dependency for the DispatcherServlet? and is the controller well defined?

Comment: Sorry I really am new at Spring, when you say "using clean", are you talking about the Maven goals? If so I'm already using `spring-boot:run clean`, as for the temp directory, could you please let me know where that is since I don't actually have a server folder in my project.

Answer (score 1):

you might be missing this part in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

`<context:component-scan base-package="hotelbooking.controller" />`

i think i see the problem. You've used value instead of path. Try using this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/hotels", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I added the line and it didn't help, I think if that were the problem the app wouldn't start due to dependency issues. I did decide to leave `<context:component-scan base-package="hotelbooking.*" />` for future proofing.

Comment: Just noticed your edit. The examples I found all used `value`, regardless, I tried with `path` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: fields 'path' and 'value' are the same behind the scenes